# How to block all Disqus content with Ublock Origin

Tags: google-chrome-extensions, adblock, ublock-origin

I heard that it is possible to use [Ublock Origin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ublock-origin/cjpalhdlnbpafiamejdnhcphjbkeiagm?hl=en) to block not only ads but also [Disqus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disqus) content on all websites that host it. Disqus is a commenting system that many websites like newspapers add to their webpages. I don't want to see it and I don't want to be tracked by it so I installed the Ublock Origin extension to my browser.

While it is blocking ads as I expect "out of the box," it is not blocking Disqus. Looking at the dashboard, all I see is a huge mess of complicated looking filters.

Can someone provide simple instructions on how to block Disqus content with Ublock Origin?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can easily add Disqus in your filters.

You just add the following:

```
||disqus.com/embed/comments/
###disqus_thread
```

To add a filter, go to the uBlock Origin Options page and go to the **My Filters** tab. Over there you just add the lines you wanna block and click **Apply Changes** on top.

Comment: Thank you. I was sick and tired of reading other peoples opinions on KissAnime... Made my day better!